# PKB: Search results almost always include a group of four or five of the same articles that have no relation to the query

Tags: knowledge, search, articles

So on our Salesforce PKB, we have about 500 different articles. However when ever a search query matches one or two articles this group of four of five has some of them show up. They have barely any words, and no tags. Here is a simplified example:

A user searches for Trees:

Results:
 - Dog
 - Oak
 - Elm
 - Cat
 - Maple

So then a user searches for something like cars:

Results:
 - Ford
 - Cat
 - Chevy
 - GMC
 - Pig

And so on. Basically, if there are no results in the first place, they don't show up. But if it a query that has any results for it, at least one of the 5 will show up in the results, despite not being related at all. Most of the time they are the first search result as well. Is there way I can stop this from happening?

Edit: I am still having this problem. Even after deleting the offending articles and re-uploading them under different titles, they still pop up at the top.

Comment: I think in this case its going to be difficult to help without a concrete example. The simple example is great to explain the problem, but doesn't aid diagnosis.

Comment: http://support.telect.com/pkb_Home_2?q=test&l=en_US

So these are search results for the term "test". The search results that include MIX 56 and MIX 28 are the articles that always seem to pop up, even though they have nothing to do with the term "test". Let me know if this helps or if I need to clarify more. Thanks for the help.